# Invoking rspec from jruby-complete 1.6.6 or above

Tags: java, rspec, jruby

So from reading the documentation, the way I'm attempting to invoke rspec is:
    java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.7.jar -S spec -b -f d rspec_sanity_check.rb

I've also tried rspec instead of spec. In each case, I get the error:
    jruby: No such file or directory -- spec (LoadError)

I'm not sure what to do here. Although the documentation says jruby-complete has rspec, I can't seem to run it.

I'm attempting to use jruby-complete to bootstrap our java based buildsystem so I don't have to install gems on each new vm.

Any thoughts on how to get jruby-complete rspec to work?

Answer (score 0):

seems to work just fine with 1.6.7 :

```
$ java -jar org.jruby/jruby-complete.jar -S rspec
Run filtered using {:full_description=>/(?-mix:Handler)/}
No examples were matched. Perhaps {:if=>#<Proc:0x8d00c6@/opt/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.12/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:50>, :unless=>#<Proc:0x12dcb8c@/opt/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.12/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:51>} is excluding everything?


Finished in 0.002 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```